# Capture scalar output of a stored procedudure which does not use output parameters and does not return a result

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, output

I have the following (simplified) stored procedure (which I'm not allowed to modify):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spDoSomething]
    @someArg INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SomeID INT

    -- some code which sets @SomeID --
    SET @SomeID = 10

    SELECT @SomeID AS SomeID
END
```

When running it from NHibernate, I see the following query in profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec spDoSomething @p0',
N'@p0 INT',
@p0=1
```

NHibernate somehow is able to retrieve the value of the `SELECT`ed @SomeID.

If I run this script in MSSQL ManagementStudio, I see the selected result.

I tried to use the same OUTPUT approach as I use for sp_executesql with simple SQL queries. For example, when I run something like

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Users ... VALUES (...); select @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()',
N'@UserId INT OUTPUT, ...',
@UserId OUTPUT, ...
```

then the result of SCOPE_IDENTITY() is stored in the @UserId.
But for some reason the same approach does not work with my [spDoSomething]. If I try the following:

```
DECLARE @ReturnedID INT

exec sp_executesql N'exec spDoSomething @p0',
N'@ReturnedID INT OUTPUT, @p0 INT',
@ReturnedID OUTPUT, @p0=1

SELECT @ReturnedID
```

then my @ReturnedID is NULL.

How do I capture the value of @SomeID into @ReturnedID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't change the SP, you can use `insert...exec`

```
declare @returnedID int

declare @t table (result int)
insert @t (result ) exec spDoSomething 
select @returnedID = result from @t

select @returnedID
```

or if you need to use sp_executesql for some reason

```
declare @returnedID int

exec sp_ExecuteSQl 
    N'declare @t table (result int);insert @t (result ) exec spDoSomething; select @returnedID = result from @t',
    N'@returnedID int output',
    @returnedID output

select @returnedID
```